# Get total amount of GPU memory?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

Is there an easy and reliable way to get the total amount of the physical GPU memory?

I have tried this, but the problem is it returns 4096MB and I'm using a GTX 780 with 6144MB, so yeah not displaying correctly.

**Code:**

```
using System.Management;        

private void getGpuMem()
{
    ManagementClass c = new ManagementClass("Win32_VideoController");
    foreach (ManagementObject o in c.GetInstances())
    {
        string gpuTotalMem = String.Format("{0} ", o["AdapterRam"]);
        Debug.Write(gpuTotalMem);
    }
}
```

Comment: As I consider `Win32_VideoController` returns max 4gb because it is win32 util.

Comment: not sure if you looked at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gpuinformation%28v=vs.95%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: What if you have more than one GPU?

Comment: I can see the 6144MB in (winSat : dedicated video memory) is there a way to use that?Well if you have multiple GPU I just going to assume they have the same amount of memory.

Answer (score 5):

As it is said in the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394512.aspx)

> Hardware that is not compatible with Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) returns inaccurate property values for instances of this class.

That is why it returns 4gb.

You can try to use [CUDAfy.net](https://cudafy.codeplex.com/)

```
GPGPU gpu = CudafyHost.GetDevice(CudafyModes.Target, CudafyModes.DeviceId);
var c = gpu.GetDeviceProperties(true);
var p = c.TotalMemory;
Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Comment: When I try that^^ with CUDAfy I get a huge number: 18446744073709551615

Comment: @PatrikFröhler it's the int64 maximum number, strange

Comment: How do I do "override ulong TotalMemory" maybe thats the issue?
http://www.hybriddsp.com/portals/0/cudafy/html/40825c56-a74f-9b79-0613-6b6fc4736dd2.htm

Comment: @PatrikFröhler It's just the method declaration. you shouldn't override anything, can you run cudafy viewer (it's an app that goes with dll)?

Comment: If I run cudafy viewer > Check for CUDA , returns : 1device GTX 780 and > Run CUDA Test, returns : CUDA directory not found.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrapper for DirectX called SharpDX. There is a compile-able example in C++
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/DirectX-Video-Memory-ee7d8319
A
you could either recreate the code with SharpDX libraries (from the NuGet Package Manager) in visual studio, or you could just compile the C++ code and call the exe as a process from within you c# code.